# How can i copy from datarow to another datatable with specific row

Tags: c#, datatable

I have this code but it just adds into the first column of the new datatable. How can i specify what column it will be added.

```
        for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            newdt.Rows.Add(dt.Rows[i][1]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that you can't use `Add` to pass the values but you can use [`SetField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360652(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow addedRow = newdt.Rows.Add();
    addedRow.SetField(1, dt.Rows[i][1]);
}
```

Or you can use the "classic" way:

```
addedRow[1] = dt.Rows[i][1];
```

I prefer `SetField` over the indexer because i don't need to fiddle around with `DbNull.Value` if i wanted to save null values. You can simply pass a nullable type like `int?`.

Comment: Or `addedRow[1] = dt.Rows[i][1]`

Comment: @bradbury9: yes, added this approach now

Answer (score 0):

Below code demonstrates, how to copy specific rows to another table.

```
//Created new table
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("dt1");
dt1.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
dt1.Columns.Add("Name");

//Added dummy data
dt1.Rows.Add(1, "Abc");
dt1.Rows.Add(2, "Def");

//Clone table #2 from table #1
DataTable dt2 = dt1.Clone();
dt2.TableName = "dt2";

//Copy table #1 rows to table #2
for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow drNew = dt2.NewRow();
    drNew.ItemArray = dt1.Rows[i].ItemArray;
    dt2.Rows.Add(drNew);
}
```